# Table column name is 'default'

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm having a hard time querying a table which has a column name 'default',
it shows an error, I can't rename it because I'm using an old system and it might affect our previous systems.

e.g.

```
select * from table_name where default = 1
```

tried this

```
select * from table_name where 'default' = 1
```

and it didn't work.

Is there a workaround on this?

Comment: ANSI SQL and most dbms products have "default", SQL Server also has [default], and MySQL has `default`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use backtips:

```
select * from table_name where `default` = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, best way.

Answer (score 4):

For SQL Server, (Not sure if you are using other db) U can use this way:

```
select * 
from table_name 
where [default] = 1
or [index] = 'another example'
```

You can [] for any column which is build-in keyword for database.

Hope this helps u.